# Tengo el error 2147417848 (80010108) en Visual basic de excel

Tags: vba

Cómo puedo solucionar el siguiente error que me aparece y ya no me funciona el programa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, pero si quieres recibir ayuda deberás mejorar tu pregunta. ¿Cuándo ocurre? ¿Hay alguna macro? ¿Qué código tiene?

Comment: Entra en las referencias y mira cuál falla, porque aparecerá precedida de la palabra FALTA si no la has eliminado ya.

Comment: Me ocurre el mismo error y este otro
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKnw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKnw.png)

Comment: Puedes probarlo con f8, ejecutar por pasos, y según leí, es problema de actualizaciones, aún no reviso esa parte.
Dudo que sea tu programa. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8-mso_2016/excel-error-2147417848-80010108-en-tiempo-de/7126ff0e-709c-42c8-82ff-4b1c66c021ed%23:~:text%3DEl%2520c%25C3%25B3digo%2520de%2520error%2520que,enlace%253A%2520Instalar%2520actualizaciones%2520de%2520Office.&ved=2ahUKEwii5-uEmaPsAhUDQ6wKHSw3Bn8QFjABegQIBhAE&usg=AOvVaw2pRYa50O7mJ1Pz95rKhyAm

Answer (score -1):

Error '-2147417848 (80010108) ///a mi se me des configuró con una actualización de Windows probablemente  me funciono volver a un punto de restauración anterior